# How to open an Excel worksheet on "worksheet Name" basis and not by the "number of worksheets" using Windows form application

Tags: c#, .net

```
Excel.Application xlApp ;
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook ;
        Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet ;
        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        xlApp = new Excel.ApplicationClass();
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("csharp.net-informations.xls", 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
        xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
```

I have the above code...but I wanted to search the worksheet based on its name and not number.

Answer (score 0):

```
string someName="My worksheet";
int i=0;
do {
    i+=1;
    xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(i);
} while(xlWorksheet.Name!=someName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
 xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
```

Use below code:

```
xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets["sheetname"];
```